# Regex for adding a versionnumber to .js and .css references in a HTML document

Tags: php, html, regex, reference, replace

I have a HTML document where I want to automatically have a version number added to all script and style sheet references.

the following should be replaced

```
 <link ... href="file.css" media="all" />
 <script ... src="file.js"></script>
 <script ... src="http://myhost.com/file.js"></script>
```

with that

```
<link ... href="file.v123456.css" media="all" />
<script ... src="file.v123456.js"></script>
<script ... src="http://myhost.com/file.v123456.js"></script>
```

where 123456 is my dynamic version number.

But it shoud ONLY do that on local files

```
<link ... href="http://otherhost.com/file.css" media="all" />
```

should be left untouched.

So far I have the following regex:

```
$html = preg_replace('#(src|href)=("|\')(?!http)(?!("|\'| |\+))(.*)\.(css|js|swf)("|\')#Ui', '\\1=\\2\\3\\4.v'.$version .'.\\5\\6', $html);
```

But it does not work 100% and I am sure that there is a better way in doing this.
How would you write it?

**Edit:**

I have it now using DOMDocument, but it turns out that it's pretty slow!

```
    <?php
//------- snip --------------
            $host       = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $refs       = array();
            $version    = "v". $version;
            $doc        = new DOMDocument();        
            $tmpDoc     = $html;

            $doc->loadHTML($tmpDoc);        
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
            foreach($xpath->query('/html/head/link/@href') as $href) {
                $ref = $href->value;
                if(
                    !preg_match('/^https?:/', $ref) || 
                    strpos($ref, $host) === 0               
                ) {
                    $refs[$ref] = preg_replace('/\.css$/', '.'.$version.'$0', $ref);
                }
            }
            foreach ($xpath->query('//script/@src') as $src) {
                $ref = $src->value;
                if(
                    !preg_match('/^https?:/', $ref) ||
                    strpos($ref, $host) === 0
                ) {
                    $refs[$ref] = preg_replace('/\.js$/', '.'.$version.'$0', $ref);
                }
            }       
            $html = str_replace(
                        array_keys($refs), 
                        array_values($refs), 
                        $tmpDoc
                    );
//------- snip --------------
    ?>
```

Comment: You can have fast (simple string replace of `.css"` to `.12345.css"`), or you can have correct (DOM parse, walk and re-serialize). You can't have both: this sort of postprocessing is not a simple task. If you need fast and correct, you'll have to change the template that produces this markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better use a HTML parser like [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/domdocument) to find the elements/attributes. Then you can use regular expressions to modify the attribute values.

Here’s an example for DOMDocument:

```
$version = 'v123456';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($code);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('/html/head/link/@href') as $href) {
    if (!preg_match('/^https?:/', $href->value)) {
        $href->value = preg_replace('/\.css$/', '.'.$version.'$0', $href->value);
    }
}
foreach ($xpath->query('//script/@src') as $src) {
    if (!preg_match('/^https?:/', $src->value)) {
        $src->value = preg_replace('/\.js$/', '.'.$version.'$0', $src->value);
    }
}
```

Comment: well that would work too, but what's with the performance? I have to do this on every page load, and caching is no option in my case.

Comment: @Alex: I think you will have to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. The replaces it makes are correct, but it changes the structure of my page. Removes whitespace on some places, and it also removes the ending tag on some tags. <img /> gets <img> for example. Probably it does not detect my doctype correctly. I will give Simple HTML DOM Parser a try!

Comment: @Alex: How do you output the changed document?

Comment: I did $html = $doc->saveHTML();

Comment: Simple HTML DOM Parser does not work at all.

I also tried phpQuery which also results in changed HTML code like DOMDocument...

Comment: @Alex: Well, `saveHTML` converts the document to HTML. When you’re using XHTML, you need to use `saveXML`.

Comment: OK when I use saveXML at least my tags keep correctly closed. But my page gets messed up anyway because it strips white space etc. 
Is there any way to alter my desired tags WITHOUT changing anything else? I think a regex would be the best solution since performance really matters at this point (~ 15-20 000 visits a day)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex, at least not to find the `src` values. Use the DOM.

```
var allScriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var allLinkTags = document.getElementsByTagName("link");

for(var i=0; i<allScriptTags.length; i++) {
    var srcAttribute = allScriptTags[i].getAttribute("src");

    // ... do something with srcAttribute ...

    // replace it with the modified value
    allScriptTags[i].setAttribute("src", srcAttribute);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I need it in PHP ;-)

Comment: I don't think the API should be much different with a PHP Dom parser.

Answer (score 1):

why not something a lot more simple like:

```
$version = 12345;
function print_local_css($base_filename)
{
    global $version;
    print '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$base_filename.'.v'.$version.'.css" />';
}

function print_local_js($base_filename)
{
    global $version;
    print '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$base_filename.'.v'.$version.'.js"></script>';
}
```

It'll be quick, one location to change the version and any files you don't want to be versioned, just manually put the HTML in.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that much influence on how the document gets created, I can just go through it before outputting it to the client.